# How to set time interval for kendotime picker in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

By default kendotimepicker have a time interval of 30 min,but i want to reduce it to 1 min.What should i do in this line to set time interval to 1 min

```
 var timepicker = $("#timepicker").data("kendoTimePicker");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really an *angular* question since you're using *jQuery*.

```
<input id="timepicker" />
<script>
$("#timepicker").kendoTimePicker({
    interval: 1
});
</script>
```

As per:
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/timepicker